# This request has no response data available

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I try to tweak and learn multiple ways to log out from a webpage. Here I am using AJAX for logging out, however it does not work.

File name: **home.php**

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <button name="logout_button">Logout</button> <span id="button_logout_id"></span>
    <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery("button[name=logout_button]").on("click", function() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'home.php',
                data: {
                    logout_session_PHP: jQuery("button[name=logout_button]").val()
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(responseJSON) {
                    jQuery("#button_logout_id").html(responseJSON.logout_msg);
                    if (responseJSON.logout_msg == "Successfully logout") {
                        window.location = "index.php";
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    
    <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['logout_session_PHP']) && isset($_SESSION['username'])) 
        {
            $_SESSION = array();
            $logout_ajax = array("logout_msg" => "Successfully logout");
            print json_encode($logout_ajax);
        }
    ?>
```

I am sorry if the answer is ridiculously simple as I am new to web development.

Comment: is there some environment available where you test it or we need to re-create it? First of all you need to understand where the problem is: does php side accepts the ajax and returns success? Does php show anything in error log? If Ajax returns error - output it in console and see what it gives. These are the steps that will help to investigate your problem

Comment: Is this supposed to be contained all in the same file? (Then you would be creating HTML output before the JSON, thereby invalidating the latter.) And why are you trying to send `jQuery("button[name=logout_button]").val()`, when that button doesn't have any value set to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. I tried to move the PHP script to a new page and it works. I'm not sure why is that so. The codes above are in **home.php**. Maybe by setting ajax `url: "home.php"` - the same page creates problem.

Comment: When you request that same script via AJAX, then it will create all the same output, as it did when you called it directly in the browser - including the `button` element, and the `script` elements. And then, at the very end, you _also_ output your JSON data. But JSON data with random gibberish in front of it (in this case, that's your HTML), is simply not valid JSON any more. If you want to do it this way, with just one file - then you need to see to it, that it doesn't output all that HTML code, in the situation when it is supposed to respond with just JSON.